# right way of testing for optional field values

Tags: java, playframework, option-type

While writing a method in my app which uses `playframework`,I need to get user input for `Address` fields and search db for a matching one.If I can't find a matching address ,I have to create a new Address.

Here only `addressLine1` and `country` are the required fields.
A user can ignore the addressLine2.

while taking input from the html form ,the textfields for optional fields return an empty string.So,to test the creation of Address ,I decided to create a `Map<String,String>` to be passed to the `POST` method..
I tried

```
addrparams = new Map<String,String>();
addrparams.put("addressline1","clayton st");
addrparams.put("country","US");
```

This caused nullpointer exception when the jpql query tried to bind values fro the map for the missing options fields.

```
String query="select distinct a from Address a where a.addressLine1=:addressline1 and a.addressLine2=:addressline2 and a.country=:country";
Address address = Address.find(query).bind("addressline1",addressline1).bind("addressline2",addressline2).bind("country", country).first();
            ..
```

I solved this by putting empty strings for all optional fields

```
addrparams = new Map<String,String>();
addrparams.put("addressline1","clayton st");
addrparams.put("addressline2","");
addrparams.put("country","US");
```

I hope this is the correct way to do this..If someone can point out better approach at testing such situations,it would help me a lot

The Address class

```
@Entity
public class Address extends Model {    
    @Required
    String addressLine1;    
    String addressLine2;        
    @Required
    String country;
...
}
```

**update:**
The stacktrace is [here](http://pastebin.com/RnyRgdL9)

The Account.java:207 where nullptr exception occurs,is this line

```
Address address = Address.find(query).bind("addressline1",addressline1).bind("addressline2",addressline2).bind("country", country).first();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is wrong. You missed the alias and the equal signs in your where clause:

```
where a.addressline1 = :addressline1 ...
```

The way you're building your map is also wrong. You put "clayton st" as addressline1, and then replace it with an empty string.

If those corrections don't work, then edit your question, paste the stack trace of the exception, and tell us which line in your code throws it.

Comment: I have added the stacktrace to the question